# OpenSeadragon Support for 16 (or even 24) bit Images

Tags: javascript, python, image, image-processing, openseadragon

I'm trying to display high definition B/W images w/ openseadragon and cannot figure out out to get more than 8 bits from the viewer. The hack I currently have is split up the high and low bits to the different color channels and re-compile in the viewer, but this is hacky and involves me converting my images to this specific format.

Does anyone know if this can be done? The tileCache seems to always be a uInt8 array.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently any way (that I'm aware of) to support anything other than 8-bit images in OpenSeadragon. There have been proposals, such as:

https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/1643

… but nothing has come of it so far. We use 2D canvas for storing our tiles and drawing the viewport, and I think that's limited to 8-bit, so that's one stumbling block. Presumably we would need to do our rendering in WebGL instead to get true 16 or 24 bit color? There are proposals for that as well, but so far no action.

If you'd like to get involved in making any of this happen, that would be awesome! Otherwise, your hack is probably the best option for now.